# iOS: how to watch when a UIView is added under control of a UIViewController while debugging?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios9

I found a view is somehow added under the control of a view controller, how can I track this process while debugging? My goal is to find where and how this view is created and added so that I could remove it since I don't need this view. Thanks.

Comment: If you can subclass the view, you can add an init method and put a break point in that. You could also try viewDidAppear if it has its own view controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Debug View Hierarchy`:

[image]

Here you can see al the views, find the one you' re looking for, select it and select `Show the Object Inspector`:

[image]

There you will see the memory address of the object, in my case I've selected a UILabel, then you can add a `watch expression` on the debug area by right clicking:

[image]

Write the address casted to your view element (again, in my case a UILabel):

```
((UILabel*) 0x14ff9c80)
```

Finally, you will see something like this:

[image]

With this you will be able to get some information of the view you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom subclass for your `self.view` in `UIViewController` and override `addSubview` and `insertSubview:atIndex` and put breakpoints there.

All added views then should trigger a breakpoint.